# buildx: failed to read current commit information with git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree

Tags: python, django, docker

I am getting this error after installing docker inside an existing project. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /code

COPY re.txt .
RUN pip install -r re.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8001

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
RUN git config --global --add safe.directory .

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver"]
```

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.11'

services:
  django:
    image: leadbracket
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
```

Comment: `RUN git config --global --add safe.directory /code`

Comment: Same error :( @sahasrara62

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue by running `docker-compose up` @Sakibovi, can you post the command you're running that results in the error?
Also, posting some lines before and after the error in your question might help in finding the issue easier.